# Functions of dates returning 00/01/1900 the first time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an **Excel spreadsheet** which has a strange behaviour, which I can't reproduce with any other.

I have a date, say `01/02/2003` in `A1`, formatted as `Date`.

If I try to use this date in a formula like `=MAX(A1)` I get `00/01/1900` (~`0`).
Indeed when evaluating `A1` with `F9` in the formula I get `"01/02/2003"`.
But if I check the parameter value with `fx` I get the date numeric value `37653`.

If I edit/enter `A1` without changing anything, the `MAX` formula updates with the correct result.
Indeed the evaluation with `F9` becomes consistent with `fx` and gives the date numerical value `37653` too.

The workaround I've found to make it works the first time is to wrap the reference with the `VALUE` function: `=MAX(VALUE(A1))`

So I have 3 questions:

- why the value is evaluated differently by `F9` and `fx` initially?
- why the date is considered text initially?
- why validating the date's cell changes the `F9` result (and consequently the `MAX` function result)?

Comment: How did the date get into the cell initially?

Comment: My guess is that fx reads the string masquerading as a date and the overhead interprets it as a true date.

Comment: What do you expect (and/or what does) `MAX([date])` return?

Comment: I would agree with @Jeeped on a quick test, `MAX(A1)` returns `01/02/2003` from entering the date and having excel auto-format the cell to date for me, I get `00/01/1900` when I enter `="01/02/2003"` in `A1` and A1 itself represents `00/01/1900` when entered as `=01/02/2003` obviously as it's just division into a now date formatted cell.

Comment: I've come across something like this a few times.  Usually when data has been copied and pasted into a cell.  It sits the looking normal, but when trying to reference it its treated as text.  Hit F2 to edit the cell or click in the formula bar and then press enter.  when I hit enter, excel reprocess what it sees at that time. and all formulas start to work again.

Comment: Thanks all :)
@Rory Dunno, but it's a "real" data, as cell is formatted as `Date`
@Jeeped Possible, I'd expect both to be at least consistent
@BruceWayne This is just a simpler example, it is to get the maximum of two dates
@Glitch_Doctor The cell is correctly identified as a `Date`; and in a new spreadsheet I can't reproduce the issue
@ForwardEd Probably yet another Excel "feature", and yes the symptoms are similar

Comment: Cell format isn't really relevant here. If you format a cell as Text and enter a date, then format that cell as Date, the contents are still text, not an actual date, and the behaviour would be as you describe.

Comment: @Rory Wow! Looks like you nail it! :)
Indeed if I format a cell as `Text`, enter `01/02/2003`, format it as `Date`, it is still considered as text (visually it remains left aligned).
Then if I revalidate the value it suddenly starts to be considered a date (visually it gets right aligned).
I'm really surprised as for me changing the format was like saying Excel `This is a date so interpret it as such from now` so I'd expect to have it right-aligned immediately.
But I was obviously wrong.
So could you please elaborate more in a dedicated answer I'll accept as the solution.
Thanks :)

Comment: @Rory I think I got it: the second time Excel is not considering that I'm "revalidating" the same value, but that I'm entering a new one, and the format `Date` acts as a hint to tell Excel that it should try to interpret my inputs into this cell as dates, so this time it reads the `01/02/2003` input as a date and overwrite the underlying value `"01/02/2003"` with date `01/02/2003`.

Comment: @Rory But not sure it explains the inconsistencies between `F9` and `fx`, so if you have another brilliant idea, it is more than welcome. :)

Comment: The `fx` dialog as @jeeped says, appears to try and coerce the arguments to the data type expected. If you enter something that can't be interpreted as a number, the `fx` dialog will show `#VALUE!`, not the actual data.

Comment: @Rory OK thanks, makes sense; but it's really confusing as visually you see the expected value `37653` but what is passed to `MAX/SUM` is the real value `"01/02/2003"` and you get `0`.
Please post your answer, I'll accept it with pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be with how the data gets into the spreadsheet.  If you're doing a manual entries then you should format the entire column to [DATE] format beforehand.  If you and pasting in data from a different source then you need to right click and [paste values] if its already in date format (xx/xx/xxxx) or standard paste if the column is already formatted.  Try formatting your spreadsheet columns and saving it.  The reopen it and work it the saved spreadsheet (with formatted columns).

Question 2 = Your date is considered text initially because you're pasting it in along with the formatting form its source.

Question 1 = Because formatting is different in in each column/cell.

Question 3 = Excel is forced to reinterpret the values in the cell.  This happens sometimes with non-date functions.  If you press f2 in a cell it shows you the formulas.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I get your point.
The cell, `A1` in my example, is correctly formatted as `Date`.
Question 1 which column/cell?
Question 2 there is no source formatting AFAIK, just a date correctly identified as `Date` by Excel
Question 3 First the source cell is a `Date` so there should be no need to reinterpret, second it's strange Excel seems to correctly identify the source value as a date only the second time